# Gazebo5 simulator ball bearings leak through bowl walls

Tags: physics, gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have created a simulation where 1000 ball bearings are put inside a bowl. What happens is that some of the balls get through the walls of the bowl, leaking outside it. Most of the balls remain inside the bowl and react properly to interactions with them, but some others, go through the bowl.

Here there is a video showing the behavior
[Ball Leaking Video](http://youtu.be/HE17muOWVLQ)

The ball bearings model is just the model provided by Gazebo.

Can anyone give me a hint about how to avoid this behavior?

My system:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- ROS Indigo
- Gazebo5 (for ROS packages)

Attached:

- The model of the bowl [model.sdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14247736261979877.sdf)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8064/gazebo5-simulator-ball-bearings-leak-through-bowl-walls/) by [Ricardo Tellez](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1118/ricardo-tellez/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,

I also noticed this bug and filed an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1433/objects-colliding-only-with-mesh-edges) report. Feel free to give it a vote/comment so it gets more attention.

This happens because the spheres only collide with the edges of the meshes, so if the mesh triangles are larger the spheres just fall through them.

For a quick workaround you can make your bowls' mesh triangles smaller. This of course will make the simulation slower.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0